# Open shared exchange email account with imap_open() PHP

Tags: php, email, exchange-server, imap-open

In exchange environment I have PHP application setup to open and IMAP stream and parse emails. I have no problem connecting to my personal email account with the following:

```
imap_open("{exchange.server/ssl}INBOX", "username", "password");
```

Now I have been given access to a group email account and I'm wondering if its possible to specify other accounts with PHP's IMAP functions. I know when I setup outlook with a new profile I add the group email then my credentials with no problems.

I've also see telnet commands that support this in *[How can I access a shared Exchange mailbox with IMAP (over telnet)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/162094/how-can-i-access-a-shared-exchange-mailbox-with-imap-over-telnet)*

TELNET: `? LOGIN domain/username/mailboxname password`

Using this logic I have tried:

```
imap_open("{exchange.server/ssl}INBOX", "username/sharedmailbox", "$password");
```

This gives an error I've also tried to add the domain with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was very close with what I posted in the question however I was including @example.com for `sharedmailbox@example.com` in the `imap_open()`. Once I removed that I had no problem connecting with the following.

```
imap_open("{exchange.server/ssl}INBOX", "domain/username/sharedmailbox", "$password");
```